# Find the total number of people who owned cars in MySQL given the schema

Tags: mysql

hey guys im doing some revision for exam and going through past papers can someone tell me if im on the right track.

Consider the insurance database given below:

```
person (driver-id, name, address)<br>
car (license, model, year)<br>
accident (report-number, date, location)<br>
owns (driver-id, license) <br>
participated (driver-id, car, report-number, damage-amount)<br>
```

1)Find the total number of people who owned cars that were involved in accidents in 2004.

here is what i came up with:

```
SELECT COUNT(driver-id)
FROM participated
WHERE participated.reportnumber=accident.reportnumber
AND accident.date = 2004
```

am i on the right track? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Mahmoud's answer below correct. Also, if you're confused about when to use a join you'll probably have a lot of trouble with the exam. You should do some "hands-on" study: sit with a copy of MySQL, create the tables, and try the queries. You'll learn the material better than way and you'll get a much better grade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, it is not right, You have to reference the `accident` table:

```
SELECT COUNT(`driver-id`)
FROM participated
INNER JOIN accident ON  participated.reportnumber = accident.reportnumber
WHERE accident.date = 2004
```

Comment: Thank you, i thought i may have to use a join.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` and join accident table

```
SELECT COUNT(a.driver-id) as total
FROM participated a
LEFT JOIN accident b
ON a.reportnumber=b.reportnumber
WHERE b.date = 2004
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DRIVER_ID) FROM person
WHERE DIVER_ID IN(SELECT DRIVER_ID FROM OWNER WHERE DRIVER_ID IN(SELECT CAR FROM participated WHERE REPORT_NUMBER IN(SELECT DATE FROM ACCIDENT WHERE DATE =2004);
```